# Can we add for loop inside a function that is called with an Unity Event

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, events, slider

I implemented a simple for loop (as below) inside a method call displayCubeInOrder();

```
public void displayCubeInOrder(Slider slider)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(slider.Value >= (i-1)/10 && slider.Value < i/10)
        {
            displayCube(i - 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I call this method under the Events, On Value Updated (SliderEventData).

However, it seems the for loop is only executed once. Appreciate any suggestion on what is going wrong here.

UPDATE:
Well, I managed to fix this. There's a huge blunder in my code snippet. My condition was never satisfied. The slider value is a float so in my condition, I am comparing float with an integer. I think (/) division in C# returns an integer. It worked when I cast the (i-1)/10 and i/10 to (float)(i-1)/10 and (float)(i/10). Again, I think it is not a good practice comparing two floats that way. Great answer from derHugo.

Comment: You mean that the first time you update the value on the slider, it works, but subsequent updates don't call displayCubeInOrder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all of course you can! ;)

tl;dr: But you don't have to in your case -> See at the bottom of this answer.

---

#### The main issue

Your condition is **NEVER** true because you are using **integer division**!

It depends of course on which values your slider can possibly have but from the usage I would assume it is something like `[0f; 1f]`.

Then the first part

```
slider.Value >= (i-1)/10
```

will probably **ALLWAYS** be `true`!! On the other hand

```
slider.Value < i/10
```

will most probably **never** be `true`!

#### Why?

Well, you are using an **integer division** and `i` will never be bigger then `10` but has values `[1; 9]` so both

```
i / 10
```

and

```
(i - 1) / 10
```

will always be `0`!

And assuming your slider has values `[0; x]` (so at least always positive) the condition

```
x >= 0
```

is always `true` while

```
x < 0
```

is never `true`.

=> I'm pretty sure your method wasn't called at all not even once by the loop.

---

You should probably make sure to use a **float division**

```
if(slider.Value >= (i-1) / 10f && slider.Value < i / 10f)
```

the `f` makes a huge difference as it turns the `10` into a `float` value and thus the `/` operator will now treat both values as `float` and also return a `float` value!

---

And well even now you still have a `break` so the loop exits after the first time the condition is `true` so it will only be executed once anyway. But this one seems to be intentional.

---

Actually though two more points:

1. You can give your method a `float` parameter, then you don't have to fetch the `Slider.Value` but already get it directly from the slider (you will have to reference it as **dynamic** callback in `onValueChanged`).

   ```
   public void OnSliderValueChanged(float sliderValue)
   { 
       ... 
   }
   ```
2. Either way you don't even need that loop at all (assuming the `break` is intentional)! Rather calculate the single index you want using e.g. [`RoundToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.RoundToInt.html)

   ```
   var index = Mathf.RoundToInt(sliderValue * 10);
   displayCube(index);
   ```

   `[0; 0.05)` → 0 
   `[0.05; 0.15)` → 1 
   `[0.15; 0.25)` → 2 
   `[0.25; 0.35)` → 3 
   `[0.35; 0.45)` → 4 
   ...

   or depending on your needs [`FloorToInt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) rounds to the next lower `int`

   ```
   var index = Mathf.FloorToInt(sliderValue * 10);
   displayCube(index);
   ```

   `[0; 0.1)` → 0 
   `[0.1; 0.2)` → 1 
   `[0.2; 0.3)` → 2 
   `[0.3; 0.4)` → 3 
   `[0.4; 0.5)` → 4 
   ...

Answer (score -1):

As @derHugo gave a nice explanation about it doesn't get executed even once.

Explaination: (Assuming slider.value = 0)

```
if(slider.Value >= (i-1)/10 && slider.Value < i/10) 

// for i==1 , 
// 0 >= (1-1)/10 //first part is true
// 0 < 1/10 //second part is false
```

condition met, if block is executed and breaks the loop.

Comment: The second part is wrong in your explanation: `0 < 0` is `false`!

Comment: No, that loops start with so i/10 is 1/10 which is less than 0.

Comment: 1/10 is not less then `0` ... 1/10 is exactly `0` ..

Comment: Yep, Sorry for that. I'll edit the answer.